# __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to send a post request to the created table but keep getting the error **init**() takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given.

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
import os

app = Flask(__name__)
file_path = os.path.abspath(os.getcwd())+"\database.db"

app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///'+file_path
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False

db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class post(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    status = db.Column(db.Boolean(50))
    title = db.Column(db.String(200))
    body = db.Column(db.String(max))
    createdtime = db.Column(db.DateTime())

def __init__(self, status, title, body, createdtime):
    self.status = status
    self.title= title
    self.body = body
    self.createdtime = createdtime


@app.route('/api/posts', methods=['GET'])
def get_all_posts():
    return ''

@app.route('/api/posts/<id>', methods=['GET'])
def get_one_post():
    return ''

@app.route('/api/new-post', methods=['POST'])
def put_post():
    title= request.get_json('title')
    body= request.get_json('body')

    new_post= post(title, body)
    db.session.add(new_post)
    db.session.commit()
    return jsonify({'message': 'Post created Successfully'})


@app.route('/api/delete-post', methods=['DELETE'])
def delete_post():
    return ''

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

What am i doing wrong?

plus my request looks something like this

```
{
 "title" : "Start before you are ready",
 "body": "This post will be a little different from what I'm used to 
 write. I tend to keep my articles in the technical realm of programming. 
 This time, I'll have to talk about a subject that transformed my mindset 
 lately. It will appear a little like a rant, and it very well may be :D"
}
```

Comment: Your init implementation doesn't actually appear to be inside the class...

Comment: Add ```__init__``` function 1 more indentation level

Comment: @VictorRuiz still same

Comment: Initialize super instance: On your ```__init__``` first line, call to ```super().__init__()```

Comment: `new_post= post(title, body)` - You are passing 2 arguments to __init__ while your __init__ looks like `def __init__(self, status, title, body, createdtime):
`

Answer (score 2):

First the `__init__` method is not the the same indentation level as the post class.
Secondly you don't need to override the default constructor of `db.Model` you can use the Post model.

For example: 
`post = Post(title='xx')` like this you can pass as many argument to it like this when you instantiate the Post class as long as the attribute you are using is in the class.